# How can an MFC VC++ application execute multiple functions within a single function without hanging or displaying a 'Not Responding' message?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, automation, mfc, winapp

As a new developer in this technology, I have a dialog initialize function. It contains around six functions for different operations. Four of these functions contain at least three to four loops, with each loop running a minimum of 19 to 35 times. I am facing hanging and application-related issues. Additionally, this is an automation-related application, involving control of motors and sensors.

I need to execute all functions without hanging or displaying a 'Not Responding' message. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Do these "operations" in threads? Ask the event-handler to run in your loops? Separate logic from the GUI (which is a good idea in general)?

Comment: First of all split the design of your code into multiple parts. The motor control should be in a seperate static libary. Which you should be able to test without any user interface at all. Then from the UI you need to run those commands on background threads.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are truly wanting to do real time control in a PC, you probably need to make the controller be its own PROCESS, and then have the User Interface be a separate process, with limited inter-process "comm" between the two.  You will have enough trouble keeping the control program running properly with just Windows overhead, let alone dealing with a GUI.

Comment: Franji1, I can understand the idea, but how can I achieve this? And could you please provide any references for this? Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: As suggested in previous comments, you can move those data creation/retrieval/processsing/etc calls (these may be blocking/syncrhonous) to a separate thread or threads, and decouple the UI and data-processing operations as much as possible (the worker thread shouldn't be modifying UI items directly and the UI thread shouldn't be controlling the motor or sensors). A "loose" communication protocol can be defined, for the threads to communicate and synchronize. Check my post at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110448/allow-start-only-one-thread/75133321) somewhat similar question.